# Search .txt file for a specific word and print data following that word

Tags: python

I am new to python so hear me out. I have been looking all over and can't find how to specifically do what I need. I request weather information from a website and then I convert it to a `.txt` file. I want to print the value next to the word I search. See below for an excerpt from `.txt` file:

```
{"cod": "200", "message": 0.004, "cnt": 10, "list": [{"dt": 1548698400, "main": {"temp": 275.32, "temp_min": 274.915, "temp_max": 275.32,
```

I want to search for `temp` and have it print `275.32`.

Added my code | API key has been removed | words related to "test" are play around variable to see if an output changes

```
import requests
import re
import time
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
curDate=datetime.now().timestamp()
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(curDate).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
system = True

while system:
    userInput=input("Type exit to leave or enter your city of choice: ")
    findExit = re.search(r'xit', userInput)
    findTheExit = re.search(r'XIT', userInput)

    if str(findExit)=='None' and str(findTheExit)=='None':
        weatherInfo = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+userInput+',us&appid=api_key_here&cnt=10')
        test = weatherInfo.json()
        testTwo = json.dumps(test)
        info=json.loads(testTwo)
        with open("Data.txt", "a") as outfile:
            json.dump(test, outfile)
# Yassine Addi code added
        with open('Data.txt', 'r') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            for item in data['list']:
                print(item['main']['temp'])
 # Yassine Addi end
    else:
        print("System turning off, goodbye")
        system=False
```

Comment: Is the file you're downloading [JSON](http://json.org/)? It probably is. If so, use Python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to load and parse it and get the number out.

Answer (score 1):

if your file is a valid `JSON`, then do this

```
import json

with open('a.txt', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
    for item in data['list']:
        print(item['main']['temp']) # prints 275.32
```

considering that `a.txt` contains

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.004,
    "cnt": 10,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1548698400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 275.32,
                "temp_min": 274.915,
                "temp_max": 275.32
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: When I add your piece it gives me this: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 4465 (char 4464)

Comment: can you paste your JSON ?

Comment: it is really long. I would have to message you it somehow.

Comment: then I suppose you're reading multiple objects from the file, correct?

Comment: I would assume so. Note: Attempted to add JSON to my post and it was over like ~60k characters

Comment: I added my code to the post so you could see how it works

Comment: Not sure what I did but now it respnds with: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: ok, I think I know what's happening, as i said earlier you're trying to read multiple JSON objects because each time the user types in a city like `Florida`, you save it *append* it to the `Data.txt` and that what causes the multiple `JSON Objects`, so i think from what i understand that you only need to *overwrite* instead of appending it. so change `with open("Data.txt", "a") as outfile:` to `with open("Data.txt", "w") as outfile:`

Comment: with w | line 341, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: It is now working. I thought I commented out line 19"info=json.loads(test)". Thank you for all the help.

Comment: yes, `json.loads` takes a string as input and returns a dictionary as output. Glad it helped.